# How to save a field after commit=False with model Form in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have a model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and a ModelForm in forms.py:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Book
```

So I'm trying to make something like this in my views:

```
def register_book(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    formul = BookForm(request.POST)
    if formul.is_valid():
        new_book=formul.save(commit=False)
        new_book.alias='foo'
        new_book.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

So, I'm saving from a html "form" the name & description, but the alias I need to save after I get the form. But isn't working.

Comment: what error is returned to you, while saving the form?

Comment: Where is the `else` for your `if formul.is_valid():` check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ModelForm` will by default include and validate all fields of the model. If you always assign the `alias` value yourself in the view, then you don't need the `alias` field in the form and you can just exclude it:

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('name', 'description')
        # NOTE: you can also use excludes, but many consider it a bad practice
```

As always, [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) can tell you more about it.

Comment: Thank you that just solves my form validation.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to save the model without an alias first. You need to allow blank values before you can do that. The recommended approach would be using [`blank`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.blank):

```
alias = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```