# WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user_slug' while using models as foreign keys from multiple apps

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In my **'bids'** app, I'm using **'order'** as foreignkey from ***'orders'*** app as

```
from orders.models import Order
from sellers.models import SellerCompany
class Bid(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
company = models.ForeignKey(SellerCompany)
bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And in my **views.py** of **orders** app, I've defined **bid** view as

```
def bid(request, order_slug):
if UserType.objects.is_seller(request.user):
    form = BidForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_form = form.save(commit=False)
        new_form.user = request.user
        new_form.order.slug = order_slug
        new_form.company.name = request.company.name
        new_form.save()
    return render_to_response('bids/bid.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    messages.error(request, 'consumer account can not bid')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

on my line

```
new_form.order.slug = request.order_slug
```

it shows an error

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'company'
```

and other error is

```
Bid has no order.
```

my **forms.py** file for **Bid** model is

```
from django import forms
from .models import Bid
class BidForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Bid
    fields = ('bid_price','active')
```

Through this exercise, i'm trying to assign **order_slug** to the **slug field** of **order** model. and **company** to the name of **SellerComapny** who is bidding.

your time n help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this through wsgi? Is it a development server?

Comment: I'm running this on **localhost**/**development server**

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the parameter "order_slug", you don't have to use request. You should use this code:

```
new_form.order.slug = order_slug
```

Comment: I tried this solution before. then it says **Bid has no order.**

Comment: In this case, the problem probably is in your form. You are receiving this error because in the variable "new_form" you don't have a Bid object, you have a form.

Comment: Check this link, I think you can find a solution looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438009/how-to-save-a-field-after-commit-false-with-model-form-in-django

Comment: Thanks for your time but I followed the same method in my **forms.py** as  described in the mentioned URL, but it throws the same error.